# Проблема с базой данных на php

Tags: php, база-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема, я просто новичок в програмировании на php и не могу пока решить даже такую элементарную проблему.[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 3):

В PHP, начиная с версии 5.3, функции mysql_* считаются устаревшими. Вместо них лучше использовать PDO подключение или mysqli.

Пруф линк: http://php.net/manual/ru/migration53.deprecated.php

Answer (score 0):

Вы обновили PHP. [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php) устаревшая функция.

**Решение проблемы:**

Хороший вариант - работать через [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php) или [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Плохой вариант - выключить "устаревшие ошибки" к примеру так:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: а почему плохой вариант?

Comment: точнее чем он плохой?

Comment: @Сергей, это сродни принятию обезболивающих общего действия для купирования болевого синдрома вместо нахождения причины. Если при этом еще где-то заболит - вы об этом можете не узнать.

Answer (score 0):

Сергей, начните использовать PDO.
А почему не стоит отключать ошибки - это не решение проблемы, используйте более безопасный mysqli_.